# How to get CSV column based on variable

Tags: powershell, syntax, properties

I am trying to create a script that should read `CSV` column-based array variables to execute some analysis on them. I have created a script that runs fine if I use the manual array column reading which is way too hard for a huge file. Is there a way to make it work when I use variables from an array?

Below is a part of the script which I am having trouble with:

```
$myarray= "col1", "col2", "col3"
$mycsv=import-csv e:\text.csv
$mycsv.$myarray[0] # this does not work
$mycsv.col1        # this works fine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell allows you to use *expressions* as property names.

In your case, because the expression involves an array subscript, you need to enclose it in `()`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

```
$mycsv.($myarray[0])
```

---

A simplified example:

```
$myarray= "col1", "col2", "col3"

$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ col1 = 'foo' }

$obj.($myarray[0]) # -> 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution :

```
$myarray= "col1", "col2", "col3"

$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ col1 = 'foo' }

$obj.psobject.Properties[$myarray[0]].Value
```

If you want a complet example for csv :

```
#columns to select
$myarray= "col1", "col2", "col3"

#import csv
$Rows = import-csv "e:\text.csv"   #csv have colum Nom, Prenom, age, autre

#take columns list into $myarray and used into csv
$PropertyToTake=$Rows | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | where Name -in $myarray

#loop on all rows csv and extract only columns values of myarray
$Rows | %{

        $CurrentRow=$_

        #create empty object
        $Object=[pscustomobject]@{}

        #Add properties to object with property name and value of csv
        $PropertyToTake | %{Add-Member -InputObject $Object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $CurrentRow.psobject.Properties[$_.Name].Value }

        #send object on output
        $Object
}
```